# Gratis visual editor for the reveal.js library

Tags: windows, gratis, javascript, gui, presentation

I'm looking for an a visual editor for the [reveal.js library](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) that meets these requirements,

- Gratis
- GUI
- Works on Windows 10
- Something very similar to [slides.com](http://slides.com)
- No restrictions (meaning basically I can make unlimited private presentations for commercial use, [slides.com](http://slides.com) only allows public presentations)

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) [Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) is a full presentation designer and presentation tool that can also export to impress html presentations, *similar to reveal.js and some argue superior,* presentations, (and more), if desired.

- Gratis - **Yes**
- GUI - **Yes** Full GUI for both presentation design and performance
- Windows 10 - **Yes** & Windows 7/8, OS-X & Linux
- Very similar to slides.com - Not exactly as it runs on your local machine but judge for yourself
- No restrictions **Yes** you can give as many public or private presentations as you like including commercially.

[image: LibreOffice Impress UI]
[image: LibreOffice Impress Export Window]

Comment: But it's not for Reveal.js...

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised it's able to export to HTML, thank you:)